# Why isn't there the "net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter" class in ehcache2.6 package?

Tags: ehcache

I want to try the page caching.
But I coundn't find the `net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter` class, so I get a error that is `class not found`

What should I do?

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>SimplePageCachingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SimplePageCachingFilter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-web/2.0.4/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/web/filter/SimplePageCachingFilter.java) was moved out of the core Ehcache jars already some time ago (IIRC) and it's now part of `ehcache-web`, add a dependency to it e.g. via maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```